# The mean cross sectional area of a volume of revolution

Tags: calculus

For example: The curve $$y= 0.001sec(x)     $$ is rotated 2π rad about the x axis to form a soild.

Calculate the mean cross sectional area of this solid in the range $[0,\pi/4]$

I am having great trouble in figuring out a method to solve this questions. Any help will be great.

(Also I have though about using the mean value of $sec(x)$ with in the range but most likely that will not work as the cross sectional area will be $sec^2(x)dx$

Comment: $\sec^2$ has an elementary antiderivative, so what's the issue?

Answer (score 1):

*A method:*

The volume is given by $$\int_0^{π/4}{πy^2\mathrm d x},$$ so that the mean area $A_m$ satisfies the equation $$A_m\int_0^{π/4}{\mathrm d x}=\int_0^{π/4}{πy^2\mathrm d x}.$$

You should be able to do something now.